# Write Binary data with python to a zip file

Tags: python, python-requests, zip

I am tying to write a binary data to a zip file.

The below works but if I try to add a `.zip` as a file extension to "check" in the variable `x` nothing is written to the file.  I am stuck manually adding `.zip`

```
urla = "some url"
tok = "some token"
pp = {"token": tok}
t = requests.get(urla, params=pp)
b = t.content
x = r"C:\temp" + "\check"
z = 'C:\temp\checks.zip'
with open(x, "wb") as work:
     work.write(b)
```

In order to have the correct extension appended to the file I attempted to use the module `ZipFile`

```
with ZipFile(x, "wb") as work:
    work.write(b)
```

but get a `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError: ZipFile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a"
```

If I remove the `b` flag an empty zipfile is created and I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

I also tried but it creates a corrupted zipfile.

```
os.rename(x, z )
```

How do you write binary data to a zip file.

Comment: @njzk2 `r` = 'raw', not regex, So he doesn't have to escape the backslashes in file names.

Comment: You can give the file whatever extension you like.

Comment: @Peter Wood That's the problem...strangely you can't if I add .`zip` the file is created but empty.

Comment: @BobDylan good point. I don't know what happened here. but is `+ "\check"` supposed to work too?

Comment: @njzk2 That string is escaping the `c` but that means nothing in python so it will just add another backslash.

Comment: @BobDylan thanks. Python is really nice :). It is probably a mistake, though, and when the folder is renamed `tcheck`, it will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't write the data directly to the zip file.  You write it to a file, then you write the *filepath* to the zip file.

```
binary_file_path = '/path/to/binary/file.ext'
with open(binary_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write('BINARYDATA')

zip_file_path = '/path/to/zip/file.zip'
with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_file:
    zip_file.write(binary_file_path)
```

Comment: or, you could use `writestr`

Comment: That does not work either.  That creates a `file.ext` and zips it. variable `b` is a zipfile thats why when manually change the file name I can extract it.

Comment: @Dan I thought `b` was binary data?  You're saying `b` is zip data?

Comment: @Dan I'm still confused.  Is the request returning binary data (not a zip file) that you want to write into a zip file, or is it actually zip file data that you want to read?

Comment: Its a zip but if I do `open(x, "w") it creates a corrupted `zip` the `binary` flag has to be included for some reason

Comment: @Dan I think it is because what you asked is not really what you "wanted" to ask.  The way your question is currently worded, it sounds like you want to write a binary data file and zip it up.  From your answers here, that doesn't sound like what you actually want.  it seems what you should really ask is "How can I write binary data to a file".

Answer (score 4):

I converted a zip file into binary data and was able to regenerate the zip file in the following way:

```
bin_data=b"\x0\x12" #Whatever binary data you have store in a variable
binary_file_path = 'file.zip' #Name for new zip file you want to regenerate
with open(binary_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bin_data)
```

Comment: I tried your code but when i try to open that zip file with archive manager, it returns an empty file. How to fix this??

Comment: Are you on mac or windows @Nimra?

Comment: virtualbox-ubuntu

Comment: -sudo yum install unzip
-unzip file.zip

Try this @Nimra

Comment: Great... It worked

Comment: @Nimra No problem. You can upvote the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `writestr` method.

```
import zipfile
z = zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'w')
z.writestr(filename, bytes)
z.close()
```

[zipfile.ZipFile.writestr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr)